# What is the name of this type of chart

Tags: data-visualization

I've tried searching Google/going through the D3 gallery to find the name of this type of chart, but I've had no luck so far. As far as I can see it is an area chart with both age and year plotted on the x axis. Does anyone know the name? And if possible a tutorial/example for Excel or even D3.js.

Edit - I think the only way to do this in Excel might be with small multiples, but if there is a 'proper name' for this chart, I'd still appreciate it.

[image]

Source: [The Coalition in 163 charts](http://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/sites/default/files/publications/4415%20IFG%20-%20Whitehall%20Monitor%20HR.pdf)

Comment: You could represent the same information with 1 x-axis, & multiple lines that are positioned vertically by value but have the same x-values (since the data do). You could have a legend to identify the lines, assisted by colors, symbols, line types, labels, etc.

Comment: Multiple-panel area time series plot? Not every graph needs a distinct name. Should not be difficult in any serious software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No specific name. It's a small multiples area chart, but usually there are no lines along the sides. The nicer ones are more like line charts with a fill below, as in this Pew Research example:

[image]

I don't know D3, but I see that Mike Bostock has a similar [small multiples example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1157787) (except vertical arrangement).

[image]

There's also [Multiple Area Charts with D3](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/29/multiple-area-charts-with-d3-js/).